# Ordering multiple functions with enable/disable options

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

I am sending an ajax request with a "data" field containing a string, as well as multiple options that the user sets. Each option will be either "enabled" or "disabled", and will act to enable or disable functions in the class. What I am wondering is if there is a better way of organizing this code that doesn't involve calling every function and checking to see if it is enabled or disabled?

```
class Parse(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = self.request.get("data")
        func1_option = self.request.get("func1_option") 
        func2_option = self.request.get("func2_option") 
        func3_option = self.request.get("func3_option") 

        newData = func1(func2(func3(data)))
        self.response.write(newData)

        def func1(foo):
            if funct1_option = "disabled":
                return foo
            else:
                return some.function(foo)

        def func2(foo):
            if funct2_option = "disabled":
                return foo
            else:
                return some.function(foo)

        def func3(foo):
            if funct3_option = "disabled":
                return foo
            else:
                return some.function(foo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Parse(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = self.request.get("data")

        # Note - order reversed
        funcs = [
            ("func3_option", some.other_other_function),
            ("func2_option", some.other_function),
            ("func1_option", some.function)
        ]
        for opt_name, func in funcs:
            if self.request.get(opt_name) != "disabled":
                data = func(data)

        self.response.write(data)
```